# Trying to understand exactly what's going on when I use useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still pretty new to React and trying to wrap my head around hooks.  I'm messing with a very simple counter example right now, using console.log() to try to understand what's going on behind the scenes:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Counter = () => {
    const [ count, updateCount ] = useState(0)
    console.log(count)

    useEffect(() => {
        updateCount(10)
        console.log(count) 
    }, [count])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Counter</h1>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => updateCount(count-1)}>-</button>
                <span>{count}</span>
                <button onClick={() => updateCount(count+1)}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I load this page, I see 0, 0, 10, 10, 10 logged to the console.  So as I understand it, this is what's happening:

1. The component is rendered, setting the default value of `count` to 0.
2. 0 is then logged to the console, as per line 5
3. `useEffect` always executes when the component is first rendered, regardless of its dependencies (right?), so it then executes `updateCount(10)`
4. Before the state is actually updated from `updateCount(10)`, 0 is logged to the console as per line 9
5. `count` updates because of `updateCount(10)`.  Because the state has changed, the component re-renders. 10 is logged to the console again as per line 5
6. Since `count` is listed as a dependency of `useEffect`, and `count` has changed, `useEffect` executes again.
7. `updateCount(10)` is called again, though it shouldn't do anything since `count` is already 10.
8. 10 is logged to the console again, as per line 9.
9. This leaves one more 10 being logged to the console, from line 5.  I'm confused why this is being executed again.  The last time `useEffect` was called, it set `count` to 10 again, but since `count` was already set to ten, the component shouldn't have a need to re-render, so why was line 5 being executed again?  Or is the component re-rendered every time an update to
   the state is called, regardless of whether the properties of the state actually change or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the third 10 logged out is because of a quirk in reacts implementation details of concurrency.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474

Normally if setState is strictly equal the component won't re render:
`updateCount(prevState => prevState)`

But if there is any ambiguity on state values (because of concurrency) react needs to do a "second" render to be certain that the state value is the same.

It definitely is an interesting quirk, and shows that you should never rely on the amount of times a component will render.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  It helps me when learning to understand why everything is working the way it is, and when this wasn't it was making me think I didn't actually grasp what was going on.  Looks like I understand the concept correctly; I just didn't know to account for this quirk.

Comment: Yeah, reading through your question it sounds like other than this quirk you know exactly what else is going on :)